# How to open more 6 browsers tabs a webpage with webpack

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a problem to display in a website ( in dev )  to display  with more 6 / 7 tabs for a page.

I use webpack & vuejs & superagent for th http request.

I can open 5 tabs, no problem. But for the tab 6, the page is totally empty and the url is good.  I don't undertand. ( I use chrome )
It's specific webpack config to allow more tabs ? It's a specific configuration for vue, vue-router ?

Thanks for your help.

edit: I see the problem en dev environment ( webpack-dev-server , ... ) but not lisible in prod environment ( file css, js, html). the problem concern the limitation of a navigator for multi browser tabs in the local domain.   But Can we change this ?  Can we modify the limitation of browser to display 10 browser tabs for exemple for firefox or chrome ?

Comment: by "tabs" do you mean browser tabs? or do you mean some vuejs "tab" construct?

Comment: oh sorry browser tabs yes :)

Comment: If you mean browser tabs, I'm frankly surprised Chrome let you open even five.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers put various limits on opening new windows (which is what opening a new browser tab is), both rate limits and limits based on when/how your code is trying to open the window (e.g., whether it's in direct response to a user action or not). I'm surprised Chrome let you open even five in rapid succession.

There's nothing you can do about this, and the limit will vary from browser to browser and over time as browsers fight their unending war against nefarious websites.

You can ask your users to update their browser settings to give your page the least "popup" restrictions, but you can't do anything in the code of your page (because if that were possible, the nefarious sites would do it, too).

You can also list the links and let the user choose to open them in new tabs. A user explicitly opening a window is always allowed.

Comment: If I understand, you mean in dev environment, i have à limit.  But in production environment not ?    If you chech many website, i don't have limitations for brower tab.   Sorry if is stupid but i'm beginning ahah

Comment: @Seb - No, there's nothing whatsoever in the answer about dev vs. production environments. Browsers limit the rate at which and circumstances in which you can open new windows from code in your page.

Comment: @Seb - browsers have no concept of development vs production environment - they just display stuff you want to display

Comment: very strange. i think is about many tabs in a local domain is limited.  I  test with the production ( file js, css, html ) and no problem with many tabs.  Like other websites.